# ERRO NO FLUTTER The method 'fazerLogin' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter

Olá, sempre que chamo algum elemento do meu Provider, recebo esse erro que esta null

```
import 'package:controlsport_app_ecommerce/helpers/validator.dart';
import 'package:controlsport_app_ecommerce/models/usuarios/user.dart';
import 'package:controlsport_app_ecommerce/models/usuarios/user_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sign_button/sign_button.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);

  final GlobalKey<FormState> formkey =
      GlobalKey<FormState>(); // key do formulario

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>(); // key Scaffold

  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController senhaController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sport\'s Control'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Form(
              key: formkey,
              child: Consumer<UserManager>(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 120.0,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/logo.png",
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
                builder: (_, userManager, child) {
                  return ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      child,

                      SizedBox(height: 20),

                      // Form Field Email
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: emailController,
                        enabled: !userManager.loading,
                        style: style,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Informe o e-mail',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                          ),
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        autocorrect: false, // não corrige o que digitou
                        validator: (email) {
                          if (!emailValid(email)) {
                            return 'Email invalido';
                          } else {
                            return null;
                          }
                        },
                      ),

                      const SizedBox(height: 16),
                      // form field senha
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: senhaController,
                        enabled: !userManager.loading,
                        style: style,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Senha',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                          ),
                        ),
                        autocorrect: false, // não corrige o q digitou
                        obscureText: true,
                        validator: (senha) {
                          if (senha.isEmpty || senha.length < 6) {
                            return 'Senha inválida';
                          } else {
                            return null;
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 7),

                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: FlatButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: const Text('Esqueci minha senha'),
                        ),
                      ),

                      // botão entrar
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 44,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                              userManager.fazerLogin(
                                usuario: Usuario(
                                    email: emailController.text,
                                    senha: senhaController.text),
                                onFail: (e) {
                                  scaffoldKey.currentState
                                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                    content: Text('Falha ao entrar: $e'),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                  ));
                                },
                                onSuccess: () {
                                  // TODO: Fechar tela de login
                                },
                              );
                            }
                          },
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          child: const Text(
                            'Entrar',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      // botaão login Google
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 44,
                        child: SignInButton(
                            btnText: 'Entrar com o Google',
                            buttonType: ButtonType.google,
                            onPressed: () {
                              print('click');
                            }),
                      ),

                      // botão login git
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 44,
                        child: SignInButton(
                            buttonType: ButtonType.github,
                            onPressed: () {
                              print('click');
                            }),
                      ),
                      // ainda n tem conta?

                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: FlatButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child:
                              const Text('Não possui uma conta? Cadastre-se'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Minha variavel esta iniciada olhe o codigo abiaxo:

```
import 'package:controlsport_app_ecommerce/helpers/firabase_erros.dart';
import 'package:controlsport_app_ecommerce/models/usuarios/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class UserManager extends ChangeNotifier {
  // config FIREBASE
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  bool loading = false;

  ///
  ////sigin
  Future<void> fazerLogin(
      {Usuario usuario, Function onFail, Function onSuccess}) async {
    print('o valor do loading é $loading');
    // resultado a auteticação
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      final UserCredential result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: usuario.email,
        password: usuario.senha,
      );
      onSuccess();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e, s) {
      onFail(getErrorString(e.code));
    } on Exception catch (e, s) {}
    setLoading(false);
  }

  void setLoading(bool value) {
    print(' o valor q esta aq eé o $value');
    loading = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool getLoading() {
    return loading;
  }
}
```

segue o erro

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'fazerLogin' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: fazerLogin(onFail: Closure: (dynamic) => Null, onSuccess: Closure: () => Null, usuario: Instance of 'Usuario')

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      LoginScreen.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:controlsport_app_ecommerce/…/login/login_screen.dart:113
#2      _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:990
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:183
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:598
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#9913a
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: ready
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(177.7, 433.5)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(145.7, 17.2)
    button: 1
```

Answer (score -2):

Nesse caso, provavelmente o erro esteja em como foi abordado os parâmetros na função fazerLogin:

Fiz alguns exemplos para entender melhor o problema, observe que a função
exemplo 1 e 3 são aceitas como correta e o exemplo2 retornará o erro:**

`The parameter 'onFail' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'`

```
class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  bool isLogged = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    exemplo1(() {}, () {});
    exemplo2(onFail: () {}, onSuccess: () {});
    exemplo3(onFail: () {}, onSuccess: () {});
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: HexColor('#FFFFFF'),
        ),
        child: ListView(
          children: [],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> exemplo1(Function onFail, Function onSuccess) async {
    onSuccess();
    onFail();
  }

  Future<void> exemplo2({Function onFail, Function onSuccess}) async {
    onSuccess();
    onFail();
  }

  Future<void> exemplo3({Function? onFail, Function? onSuccess}) async {
    onSuccess!();
    onFail!();
  }
}
```

Eu encontrei uma postagem que explica de forma clara essa questão de parâmetros no Dart. Espero que ajude, também estou aprendendo. Vou deixar o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560461/the-parameter-cant-have-a-value-of-null-because-of-its-type-in-dart) para quem quiser fazer a leitura. Um abraço!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).